# Linux to define Custom Shell Command?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to simply define a custom shell command, for example:
I type `abc` and it will output some text.

Like:

```
$ abc
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

- How to make it simply in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **alias**

```
alias abc="echo The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

you can add it into your ~/.bash_profile to make it valid for all sessions.

Comment: Is it permanent? What if i reboot my machine? (or) Is there a setting/config file storing for that alias commands?

Comment: @4lvin yes. In Mac OSX, you can put it into ~/.bash_profile; in Ubuntu or other linux systems, you can put it into ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 7):

You also should consider learning about [bash functions](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) so you would have

```
 function abc () {
   echo The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 }
```

and as others told you, you could also use bash `alias` builtin.

<sup>You may want to remove the bash-specific `function` keyword to be portable to other Posix shells.</sup>

The main advantage of functions in bash is that they can take some arguments and be more complex than what `alias` give you.

Comment: Note that the keyword `function` is not needed and not portable.  Simply omit it to work in any Bourne shell.

Comment: Thanks. Added a note about that.

Comment: *"omit it to work in any Bourne shell"* as long as you don't use any other bashism in the function, so that you are faced with the usual choice between legacy support and spiffy features of the newest, specialest version.

Answer (score 1):

`alias abc='echo The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'`

Comment: Is it permanent? What if i reboot my machine? (or) Is there a setting/config file storing for that alias commands?

Comment: @4lvin: Put it in your ~/.bashrc or equivalent.

Comment: add it in either .login file or .bashrc file

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood your requirement correctly ,you can use alias command for this

```
alias abc='echo "testing"'
```

Comment: Is it permanent? What if i reboot my machine? (or) Is there a setting/config file storing for that alias commands?

Comment: Its not permanent. As you reboot it will go away. To overcome this you can this alias in .bashrc (in your home directory)