# Decompile Linux shell commands

Tags: linux, shell

This question is reverse of [Linux to define Custom Shell Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909141/linux-to-define-custom-shell-command)

I know we can read the documentation about most of the commands using man/info/help/?.
Is there any way to "decompile" any shell command and know how it executes.

Comment: Just download the code: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/ and look what it does. No need to decompile anything, Linux is open source.

Comment: Does `bash -x shell-script` (or `anyshell -x shell-script`, usually) provide you the information you're after?  It tells you about the commands which are executed by the script, and what they're arguments are.  But you may be looking for something else.

Comment: bash -x did not work, i got this error:
bash -x ls
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file

Comment: `bash -x` or `sh -x` will attempt to give you line-by-line debugging info about your **shell script** as it runs. It can be enabled or disabled from inside the script with `set -x` and `set +x` respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call it with `strace` to see how it interacts with the kernel.
If you really feel like reading assembly, there's `objdump -d`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great, are there any other tools or documentation, I am excited to learn kernel level programming.

Comment: There's typical c tools (make, gdb, valgrind, perf), and for documentation manpages, Documentation/ in the kernel tree, and books on Unix programming and OS design.